# Solving $a = b^x \mod c$ where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are large integers

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am trying to solve this problem :

---

Given $a$, $b$, $c$ integers (that could be very large), find $x$ integer such as :

$a=b^x \mod c$

---

I tried by coding in C a loop checking the equality and incrementing x, but I assume they are faster ways to do that. What are the best **exisiting** algorithms for solving this problem, with big $a$, $b$ and $c$ ?

Comment: This is the discrete logarithm problem and best solved by either inventing a quantum computer or finding a job at the NSA.